# How to manage ui-router or share $scope in different $state

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router

I have an AngularJS site, the object-resource I want to show is:

1. each user has a basic account, that will show in a single page (named `basic-page`);
2. user has several sub-account, each sub-account will show in a diffent page (named `app-page`);
3. `basic-page` will show the summer info about the sub-account, so `app-page` can share the `loaded $http data` of `basic-page` is better for code reusing.

As the purpose, I use `ui-router` define state below:

```
.state('user', {
    url: '/user/{id}',
    title: 'User-Page',
    templateUrl: helper.basepath('user.html')
})
.state('user.app', {
    url: '/{app}',
    title: 'App-Page',
    emplateUrl: helper.basepath('app.html')
})
```

Notice that state `user.app` is the child of `user`.

What I want is when I enter the `user.app`, it can reuse the data in `user`, ecen if it's a different page, that the `user` need not to contain a `ui-view` to include `user.app`'s template.
But actually I enter `user.app`, and it doesn't show the `app.html`(because I didn't include ui-view in `user.html`).

Maybe this is not the correct usage of ui-router.

So, how can I share data in different `$state`? Anyone can give me a detailed example? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

**Sharing data across controllers**

Any time you need to share data across states you will need to create a service/factory that you can instantiate in your controllers associated with those states.

The factory will consist of basic getters and setter for the different data you need to share. Just like when you build getters and setters in java to share across classes.

**Example Code**

```
.factory('yourFactory', function ($scope) {
  return {
    get: function () {
        return $scope.someValue;
    },
    set: function(value){
      $scope.someValue = value;
    }
  };
})
```

Disclaimer: I've not tested this code but it should do the job for getting and setting some values you need to access across your app.

**Demo** : Working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/hf3urXOaKDnsfuDbMnek?p=preview) with this approach.

**Alternative: 1**

This is the "Dirty" alternative, you can set a global variable with `$rootScope`. It will be accessible everywhere since its global, I strongly advise you don't do this but though I would point it out to you anyway.

**Alternative: 2**

When a state is "active"—all of its ancestor states are implicitly active as well.So you can build your states considering the parent-child relationship and share data across scopes in hierarchical manner. 
[Official Docs](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-and-Nested-Views) and working [plunker](http://embed.plnkr.co/Jbli2GECwcD3QQTjL8fd/preview) with mentioned approach.

Comment: I've added some untested code, It should give you an idea of what to add in your project

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer.  I have updated your plunkr to utilize the $http promise for the detail view.  This should make the detail view bookmark safe

Comment: The factory i wrote here is wrong. You cannot use $scope in it. I've actually written a gist on git hub showing the correct way to share data but I'm only on my phone atm. Once I get to my laptop I'll update this answer complete with a link to the gist.